# Is there any way to create an Intent that takes a type with an overloaded constructor?

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I'm creating an `Intent` for a `Service` that I have:

```
_myServiceIntent = new Intent(this, typeof(MyServiceCls));
```

This works, but `MyServiceCls` has dependencies. Is there any way for me to pass these in to `MyServiceCls` rather than create instances of them in the default constructor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way of sending data to a service is through intents, but that will mean the parameters are serialized/parceled, so not helping ...

I see two ways of doing it:

1. *The complicated solution*: You could create a binded service with [remote messenger](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#RemoteMessengerServiceSample); once the service is connected, you can send to the Incominghandler a [`Message`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Message.html) for each reference you need. But thinking again, I believe that will serialize the object and the service might get another instance ... So, maybe the simple solution is the best for you:
2. *The simple solution*: Why don't you use an IoC (Inversion of Control) mechanism? You could integrate [RoboGuice](https://github.com/roboguice/roboguice), [AndroidAnnotations](https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations) or [Dagger](http://square.github.io/dagger/).

2.1 If you don't want (it's not the time right now) to integrate above APIs, you could have a singleton class in the project that keeps the instances you need, you would initialize this class in `Application.onCreate()`, lazy load (or not) the objects you need and provide getters for each. And then in your service you call call get for each of those objects you need from singleton class.